# Symfony2 authentification : redirect 302 on POST request

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have an issue with Symfony authentification.

My security.yml file looks like this :

```
providers:
    corebundle_admin:
        entity:
            class:    CoreAdminBundle:Admin
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    admin:
        pattern: ^/admin
        form_login:
            provider:    corebundle_admin
            login_path:  /admin/login
            check_path:  /admin/login
        logout: true
        anonymous: true

access_control:
   - { path: ^/admin/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And my controller :

```
  /**
   * @Route("/login")
   * @Method("GET")
   */
  public function loginAction() {
    return $this->render('CoreAdminBundle:Admin:login.html.twig');
  }

  /**
   * @param Request $request
   *
   * @Route("/login")
   * @Method("POST")
   */
  public function checkAction(Request $request) {
    // do something
  }
```

Everything works fine, but when i'm trying to send a POST request to /admin/login, the response is a 302 and redirects to /admin/login ...

I'm stuck here, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change your login check action to :   /login_check or any name expect '/login' it will work

```
  /**
   * @Route("/login")
   * @Method("GET")
  */
 public function loginAction() {
   return $this->render('CoreAdminBundle:Admin:login.html.twig');
 }

  /**
   * @param Request $request
  *
 * @Route("/login_check")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
 public function checkAction(Request $request) {
  // do something
 }
```

edit your security.yml

```
         provider:    corebundle_admin
        login_path:  /admin/login
        check_path:  /admin/login_check
```

Comment: Same problem. I don't know why but the POST request always redirect 302, if I set it with GET it works ... Anyone can explain me why ?

Comment: try add  this tag inside your form :
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
        value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
    >
i

Comment: Unfortunately, same result